# Поддомены apache htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, поддомены

У меня есть VPS-машинка с установленным на ней apache 2.2 + php. Я пытаюсь настроить автоматические поддомены. Доступ ко всем необходимым для этого файлам на сервере, естественно, есть. Однако после того, как все вроде бы настроил возникла проблема:
mod_rewrite, перед тем как перейти на указанную в субдомене страницу, меняет url c sub.domain.com на domain.com/sub, что достаточно очевидно, ведь именно это в htaccess ему и прописано, как я понимаю.

Так вот. Вопрос в том, как (желательно не прибегая к php) сделать так, чтобы в адресной строке не отображалась директория, а оставался поддомен sub.domain.com без видимого преобразования url?

Comment: конфиги в студию

Comment: Проблему уже давно решил. Если нужно, могу выложить конфиг

Comment: @luxor, выкладывайте. Для потомков пригодиться. А если что не так, то мы с удовольствием минусами закидаем )) Шучу ;)